# Dynamic image changing from a URL

Tags: java, android, image-loading

I'm working on an android project right now and I'm trying to change the background image of my button. Here is the problem. I should get this image from an url but this url changes time to time. Everytime that url image changes I need to change my image in my android project too. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can set an image as background of a Button using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

```
GlideApp.with(this).load(IMAGE_URL).into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            yourButton.setBackground(resource);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: But here is the thing. There is no single url.  Url is in inside an html <img> component and it is constantly changing.

Comment: Then you have to parse that URL and send it to `load()` method of `Glide`.